# Copy new and modified files to different folder with Gulp

Tags: gulp

I'm trying to set up a gulp task which scans my development folder for any new or changed files, and then copies them to my local server with the same folder structure. And it should also do this every time I edit or change a file.

I seem to have something that kinda works, but it's extremely slow up to the point where I don't know if it actually works at all. (The notification message doesn't show up at all after 30+ minutes)

Could someone point in the right direction on how to set this up correctly?

```
// Server folder
var projectWWW = 'C:/wamp64/www/myproject';

// Files to be copied (everything excluding scss files)
var copySRC = ['./**/*', '!./**/*.{scss}'];

// Require gulp & plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');

// Copy files task
gulp.task( 'copyFiles', function() {
    gulp.src( copySRC )
        .pipe( newer( projectWWW ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( projectWWW ) )
        .pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "copyFiles" Completed!', onLast: true } ) );
});

// Watch tasks
gulp.task( 'default', ['copyFiles'], function () {
    gulp.watch( copySRC, [ 'copyFiles' ] ); // Copy on file changes.
});
```

Comment: does your project have node modules inside it ?

Comment: @Rajatbanerjee Ok I sure feel stupid now. That fixed the loading part, but the file copying still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: hey, no such thing as stupid question. Are you saying that the copy does not work ?

Comment: i ran the same code on my local for a test app and it works. the only thing i can think of is permission, since you are making a folder at root level
var copySRC = ['./**/*', '!./node_modules/**'];

Comment: Rewrote the `copySRC` after your comment and now it works! Thanks!

Comment: i will move it as my answer and you can accept and close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ran the same code on my local for a test app and it works.

```
var copySRC = ['./**/*', '!./node_modules/**'];
```